# joining two database tables in mysql and laravel

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables.

`as_tbl_company_holidays`

```
id  year company_id start_date, end_date, description
1  2020   1 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 New Year Holiday
2  2020   1 2020-02-14 2020-02-15 Valentine Holiday
3  2020   2 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 New Year Holiday
```

`as_tbl_employee_holidays`

```
id employee_id company_id year start_date end_date description
1  ASL100  1  2020-01-31 2020-01-31 Casual Holiday
2 ASL200 2 2020-04-01 2020-04-02 Easter Holiday
```

How can i join these two table to get a holiday data for a particular employee i.e.

```
id employee_id company_id year start_date end_date description
1  ASL100  1 2020 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 New Year Holiday
2 ASL100 1 2020 2020-02-14 2020-02-15 Valentine Holiday
3  ASL100 1 2020-01-31 2020-01-31 Casual Holiday
```

```
id employee_id company_id year start_date end_date description
1  ASL200 2 2020 2 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 New Year Holiday
2  ASL200 2 2020 2 2020-04-01 2020-04-02 Easter Holiday
```

Meanwhile, I wrote this SQL query and it's returning duplicate data. How can I combine the data from both tables into one.

```sql
select 
    emp.employee_id, 
    comp.company_id, 
    comp.year, 
    comp.start_date, 
    comp.end_date 
from 
    as_tbl_company_holidays as comp 
left join as_tbl_employee_holidays as emp on comp.company_id = emp.company_id 
where 
    emp.employee_id = "ASL100" and 
    comp.company_id = 1
```

Comment: You've stated MySQL in the title and tagged SQL Server in the tags - these are conflicting RDBMS - please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @DaleK, it was a mistake, I corrected it. Please i need assistance on this

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a `union` query instead of join

```
select company_id,year, start_date, end_date,description
from as_tbl_company_holidays
where company_id = 1
union 
select company_id,year, start_date, end_date ,description
from as_tbl_employee_holidays
where company_id = 1 
  and employee_id = "ASL100"
```